# Python LinkedList with two arguments

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I want to create a linked list where each node's cargo has two pieces of data.

This is what I've got so far, it runs without errors, but produces no output.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.head = None
        self.label = data[0][0]
        self.value = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])

    def __iter__(self):
        node = testlist.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next

testlist = LinkedList()

print([node.value for node in testlist])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems with your code:

1. Your `__iter__` method doesn't iterate over `self`, it iterates over `testlist` (which isn't in itself a problem for your specific test case, but this is going to break in any other situation)
2. Your `__init__` method does not actually construct a linked list.  It simply initializes `head` to None, which means that your `__iter__` will never have anything to traverse.
3. Nothing uses your `Node` class.  In a typical linked list implementation, the `head` of the list would be a `Node` representing the first element of the list, the `next` of that `Node` would be the second element, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Still new to this, I've looked at my program's logic again and got everything working.